# Template_redirect for child custom post types

Tags: templates, template-redirect

I currently have a custom post type called 'Services' which has two levels (parent and child).

I need to load three different templates within this post type (1 for the parent, and two different ones for the children'.

Can anyone please explain how I might go about achieving this?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter. This should be a start to get you going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sorted. For any one interested, I simply added in a function (into functions.php) that redirected to my new template dependent on the name of the post (you could also use the ID).

```
add_filter('template_include', 'new_template');

 function new_template($template){
       global $post;
       if($post->post_name == 'mortgage'){
           $template = get_template_directory() . '/mortgage-template.php';
       }
       return $template;
 }
```

Comment: You should not be using `template_redirect` here. Use `template_include` as I suggested in my comment

Comment: +1 for posting your solution. Remember to visit this answer again after two days to accept it. :-)

Comment: Previous answer wasn't working so have updated the working version. Thanks again.